# Using ClickOnce when i need to generate several large files?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm building a digital signage application and I want to deploy it using ClickOnce.  (I feel this is the best approach.) When I start the application from Visual Studio (VS) it works great. The application downloads a lot of images from my web service and saves them to disk:

```
string saveDir = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName;
```

When I start my deployed application, it shows the splash screen and then disappears.  The process keeps running, but the UI doesn't display. I'm wondering if my `saveDir` as shown above is giving me trouble?

How do I locate my installed application? (I need to make license files, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the root of your problem, but I highly recommend you change the structure of how you store your application information.

When an application is installed through ClickOnce, the application is installed within the User's folder, and it's considerably obfuscated.  Furthermore, locations may change with subsequent application updates, so you can not be guarantee than any cached, downloaded file will exist from update to update.

To solve this problem, ClickOnce does provide a `Data` directory, that is not obfuscated and can be used for caching local data.  The only caveat is this directory is not available for non-ClickOnce instances of your application (like the version that is running within the VS debugger.)

To get around this, you should write a function that you can use to get your data directory, regardless of your method of distribution or execution.  The following code is a sample of what the function should look like:

```
//This reference is necessary if you want to discover information regarding
// the current instance of a deployed application.
using System.Deployment.Application;

//Method to obtain your applications data directory
public static string GetAppDataDirectory()
{
    //The static, IsNetworkDeployed property let's you know if
    // an application has been deployed via ClickOnce.
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)

        //In case of a ClickOnce install, return the deployed apps data directory
        //  (This is located within the User's folder, but differs between
        //  versions of Windows.)
        return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;

    //Otherwise, return another location.  (Application.StartupPath works well with debugging.)
    else return Application.StartupPath;
 }
```

Comment: Why `StartupPath`? Likely won't have permissions on Vista/W7/W8. [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) can help find a better one.

Comment: Thanks, if i allow the user to browse for a folder on disk, say with a lot of images in it, will my application then be able to access e.g. c:\myimages all the time?

Comment: @BrianHvarregaard: as long as they have permissions to that folder every time you run it.

Comment: @6LV: Yes, your approach is better when accessing a location for a deployed application, that was deployed via CD or some other because the snippet came from an old example and that case will most likely be used for debugging and from that vantage point I, personally, like to keep my data in the test folder.  Your approach is certainly better for a broader public that may find this solution for a loosely similar problem.  I'll modify my remarks and make a comment about it.